# Sql create table with alternate row from two different table

Tags: sql-server

I'm having two table which contain data for reviler for employee on shift basis

e.g

```
Table 1
------
ID  NAME    RELIVERID
------------
20  ABC       56
----------
21  XYZ       57
----------
22  DEF       58
----------

TABLE 2 
---------
ID  NAME    RELIVERID
-------
56  PQR         20
-----
57  STU         21
----- 
58  XYZ         21
----
```

I want result in third table with following data

```
Result Table
-------
ID  NAME    RELIVERID
---
20  ABC       56
-
56  PQR       20
-
21  XYZ       57
-
57  STU       21
-
22  DEF       58
-
58  XYZ      21
-
```

1 row  from first table and alternate row from second table

Comment: data inside a table has no sequence. just put data from both the tables into the target table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the row_number function, multiply it with a factor for the 1st table and for the second table add 1 so it will be greater than the one in the 1st table and perform an union all. I don't a SQL Server instance to test this, but it should be something like this:

```
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC)) * 100 AS OrderID, * FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC)) * 100 + 1 AS OrderID, * FROM Table2
ORDER BY OrderID
```